# Windows 10 IoT RPi3 default controller driver

Tags: driver, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

What is the difference between "Inbox driver" and "Direct Memory Mapped driver"? My basic LED blink remote application worked only after selecting Direct Memory mapped driver. What is the unique things associated with this driver?

[image]

Comment: Hello, which driver did you use in your remote application,Lightning driver of default driver?

Comment: I had to switch to Lightning driver in order to make my first deployment work, but I'm not able to understand what difference does it make.

Answer (score 1):

The Direct Memory Mapped Driver([DMAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/lightningproviders#about-the-direct-memory-mapped-driver-dmap)) is an in-developement driver that provides GPIO performance improvements over the default inbox driver. If you use Lighting Driver in your application, you should set the controller driver as *Direct Memory Mapped Driver*,or there will be exception thrown.As far as i know,there is no more official statement about the detailed difference.